# WPF ComboBox disallow selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, filter

I have a `ComboBox` that is being declared as follows:

```
<ComboBox 
    Name="cmb" Height="20" Width="125" Margin="5,3,0,0" 
    Text="{Binding SomeList}"
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}"
    IsEditable ="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

I'm trying to filter the list of items based on what's typed in the `ComboBox`. Now, I've tried custom controls, handling the `KeyUp` event of the `ComboBox` and so on but the one problem I constantly come across is that the moment I type a letter in the `ComboBox` the very first matching item is populated in the `TextBox` and then the filter returns only that matching item making the list have only one item. Here is the `KeyUp` event handler and the `FilterPredicate`:

```
private bool FilterPredicate(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return false;

    if (cmb.Text.Length == 0)
        return true;

    string prefix = cmb.Text;

    return value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(prefix.ToLower());
}

private void cmb_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cbSender = sender as ComboBox;
    cbSender.Items.Filter = null;
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Escape || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab ||
        e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
    {
        cbSender.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
    else if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down)
    {
        cbSender.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (cbSender.HasItems)
        {
            cbSender.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The Filter for the `ComboBox` is bound to the `FilterPredicate` in the constructor.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the isTextSearchEnabled property did the trick for me.